# How to apply an Easing algorithm in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I want to move the Camera with a smooth motion so I am writing this script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraScroll : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject targetCamera;

    private bool  isScrolling = false;

    private Vector3 initialPosition;
    private Vector3 scrollTarget;

    private float scrollDuration;
    private float scrollTick;

    private float timeStartedScrolling;


#region Easing

    float EasingInOutSine(float time, float start, float change, float duration) {
        return -change/2 * (Mathf.Cos(Mathf.PI*time/duration) - 1) + start;
    }

    float EasingOutSine(float time, float start, float change, float duration) {
        dynamic td = time/duration;
        return change * Mathf.Sin(td * (Mathf.PI/2)) + start;
    }

    float EasingInOutBack(float time, float start, float change, float duration) {

        float td2 = time/(duration/2.0f);

        float s = 1.70158f;

        if ((td2) < 1.0f) {
            return change/2.0f*(td2*td2*(((s*(1.525f))+1.0f)*td2 - (s*(1.525f)))) + start;
        } else {
            return change/2.0f*((td2-2.0f)*(td2-2.0f)*(((s*(1.525f))+1.0f)*(td2-2.0f) + (s*(1.525f))) + 2) + start;
        }

    }

#endregion


    void Start() {

        if (targetCamera == null) {
            targetCamera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
        }

        // Tests

        //Scroll(new Vector3(4.0f, 0.0f, -10f), 2f); // seems to be working?
        //Scroll(new Vector3(4.0f, 0.0f, -10f), 0.3f); // easing gets cut off
        Scroll(new Vector3(4.0f, 0.0f, -10f), 1f); // easing gets cut off

    }



    void Update() {

        if (isScrolling) {

            scrollTick += Time.deltaTime;
            float s = scrollTick / scrollDuration;

            float timeSinceStarted   = Time.time - timeStartedScrolling;
            float percentageComplete = timeSinceStarted / scrollDuration;

            if (percentageComplete > 1.0f) {

                isScrolling = false;
                Debug.Log("Scrolling ended");

            } else {

                                           // time,     start, change,                                  duration
                var easing = EasingInOutSine(Time.time, 0,     Mathf.Clamp01(Time.time*scrollDuration), scrollDuration);

                targetCamera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initialPosition, scrollTarget, easing);



            } 

        }

    }

    void Scroll(Vector3 targetPosition, float duration) {

        scrollDuration = duration;
        scrollTarget = targetPosition;
        initialPosition = targetCamera.transform.position;
        timeStartedScrolling = Time.time;
        isScrolling = true;

    }

}
```

The problem is that the motion of the camera is cutoff and the easing is not applied properly if the duration is set to be 1 second or lower

I'd like the script to be able to use different easing algorithms in the future and play with deltaTime properly, I am not sure if I am doing it the right way

Comment: I know you are seeking a solution to fix your code however I truly recommend that you take a look at this library [DOTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676) as it's super fun and helpful!  You could perform easing and much more in a couple lines of code.

Comment: I've seen DoTween, it's really good but it's closed source even when you buy it and I don't want to use it as a result. Plus I want to learn how to do the above.

Comment: Your code has some issues. you defined `s` in Update but never used it and instead of that you are using `easing` which is never defined. Can you please check that? And as for the cutoff I think that's in your `percentageComplete` which is probably becoming greater than 1.0f a lot hence not doing the easing

Comment: Also Unity now has cinemachine for both 2D and 3D which includes a smooth camera follow. You don't need to implement your own, try 'Unity Cinemachine'

Comment: The thing is that I don't wanna use Cinemachine because I don't plan to have only smooth following, I might just use exponential easing or elastic etc.

Yeah, you're right about `s` but I am a little confused. scrollDuration should be normalized to...1? It seems percentageComplete reports back the wrong value and the motion gets cutoff prematurely

Comment: Just a note that the [DOTween website](http://dotween.demigiant.com/) says it is open-source and points to this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween).

Comment: I probably yoinked [these](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/util/MathHelper.cs#L20-L48) *from* DOTween. I'm not sure where I snagged them from at this point, but they're pretty well known functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a constant change.

With an increasing change the slow down effect of the easing will be overpowered by the exponential movement caused by the increasing change. This effect is most apparent in low duration movements because it will never reach the value ceiling slower so it will keep speeding up until the end.

Since your using your easing algorithm to output a percentage to throw into a lerp, you probably want to use a change of 1 so that the easing interpolates between 0 and 1.